# Why line declared 'containing no code' in gcov

Tags: c++, gcc, gcov

I am trying to analyze code coverage in c++ program using gcov. An output line I got is:

```
//my_header.h.gcov
-:  349:    TArray<unsigned,1,8> my_var;
```

According to [gcov documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov) it means that 'line 349 contains no code'.

As one can clearly see, this line contains code, namely a declaration. 
I would really like to understand what happpens there.

Comment: I think it means no *executable* code, therefore nothing for which coverage is a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarations are really just information for the compiler, and no executable code is generated. Therefore, there's nothing in this file to determine coverage for.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand it, but having something like `int x` is declaration and definition in one line. So actually it would be 'executable code'. Why isn't `TArray<unsigned,1,8> x` executable code? How does the compiler know that it has to do nothing there?

Comment: If `TArray<unsigned, 1, 8>` has no code in the constructor, there is really nothing for the program to do on this line. It's just information "a variable of this type exists in this space." What executable code would you expect?

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think I got it: If there was a constructor, an object would have been created on the stack, otherwise nothing happens...

Comment: @ProfHase85: Hard to be certain without more context, but I think it unlikely this object would be created on the stack. It's more likely in static data or part of an object.

Comment: @ProfHase85: *If there was a constructor, an object would have been created on the stack, otherwise nothing happens*, this is not really true. A variable **is** created, it is just that no code is used to initialize it (the creation of all variables in a function --allocation of space-- is usually conflated into a single increment of the frame pointer, so there is no code generated for allocation of each variable)